# Deriving the method of constrained variation for optimization of multivariable functions subject to equality constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm trying to follow Rao's exposition on the method of constrained variation to optimize a two-variable function subject to an equality constraint, but am having a hard time doing so. It goes:

> The basic idea used in the method of constrained variation is to find a closed-form expression for the first-order differential of $f$ ($df$) at all points at which the constraints $g_j(X)=0$, $j=1,2,...,m$, are satisfied. The desired optimum points are then obtained by setting the differential $df$ equal to zero. Before presenting the general method, we indicate its salient features through the following simple problem with $n=2$ and $m=1$: minimize $f(x_1, x_2)$ subject to $g(x_1, x_2) = 0$.

> A necessary condition for $f$ to have a minimum at some point $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ is that the total derivative of $f(x_1,x_2)$ with respect to $x_1$ must be zero at $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$. By setting the total differential of $f(x_1,x_2)$ equal to zero, we obtain: $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2=0$$

My first question is whether the condition that $df$ be zero at an optimum is actually necessary in a constrained optimization problem. My understanding was that it was not, but it seems like the author is making the opposite point. Also, why is he speaking of the "total derivative with respect to $x_1$"? The expressions looks perfectly symmetrical with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$.

> Since $g(x_1^*,x_2^*)=0$ at the minimum point, any variations $dx_1$ and $dx_2$ taken about the point $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ are called admissible variations provided that the new point lies on the constraint: $$g(x_1^*+dx_1,x_2^*+dx_2)\simeq g(x_1^*,x_2^*)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x_1^*,x_2^*) dx_1 + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}(x_1^*,x_2^*) dx_2 = 0$$ where $dx_1$ and $dx_2$ are assumed to be small. Since $g(x_1^*,x_2^*)=0$, the equation reduces to $$dg=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} dx_1 + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2} dx_2=0$$ at $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$.

This part is what really puzzles me. How did they go from $\simeq$ to $=$ without any justification in doing so? Disregarding the higher-order terms in the Taylor expansion on account of $dx_1$ and $dx_2$ being assumed small seems a bit too lax on rigor. So what gives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard topic in multivariable calculus. Here is quick explanation that uses only the chain rule. for the case you mentioned above (one constraint in two variables).

Thinking of the constraint $g(x,y)=c$ as defining a smooth curve in the plane , as you travel along this curve $(x(t), y(t))$ (parametrized as a function of time)
the Chain rule tells you $g_x\dot x+ g_y \dot y \equiv 0$ for all times.

If however you are also at a constrained local min or max of $f(x,y)$ then  again by the chain rule $f_x \dot x+ f_y \dot y=0$ as you pass  through that special point.

The pair of equations above implies that  the two rows of this system of linear equations for $<\dot x, \dot y>$ must be proportional, so

$ <f_x, f_y>= \lambda <g_x, g_y>$ for some proportionality constant $\lambda$. (You can check this if you  solve for $\dot y/\dot x$ two ways, using the two equations.)

Often this Lagrange Multiplier condition is restated  more concisely by saying that an auxiliary function $ f- \lambda g$ has both of its partial derivatives equal to zero.